# How to find expectation value $p_y$ from the Bloch sphere?

Tags: probability, rotations, spherical-coordinates, quantum-computation, quantum-information

Consider an arbitrary state:
$$|\psi\rangle = a|0\rangle+b|1\rangle,$$

where $a=cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right), b=sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)e^{i\phi}$ (neglecting global phase), $\phi$ is the polar angle, $\theta$ is the azimutal angle on the Bloch sphere.

The Bloch sphere vectors can be found as:
$$r_z=cos\left(\theta\right), r_x=sin\left(\theta\right)cos\left(\phi\right), r_y=sin\left(\theta\right)sin\left(\phi\right)$$

If I want to project this state $|\psi\rangle$ into the state $|1\rangle\langle1|$, I can get $p_z$ component of the Bloch vector:

$$p_z = |\langle1|\psi\rangle|^2 = |\langle1|\left(a|0\rangle+b|1\rangle\right)|^2 = |b|^2 = sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) = \frac{1-cos(\theta)}{2} = \frac{1-r_z}{2}$$

To find another two expectation values $p_x$ and $p_y$ I need to change the basis of initial state (which is $|0\rangle$) by rotating the Bloch sphere vector by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ around $X$ or $Y$ axis of the Bloch sphere.

Here is the derivation for the expectation value $p_x$ (after rotating the Bloch sphere vector by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ around $Y$ axis):

X-axis basis states:$$ |+\rangle = \frac{|0\rangle+|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}, |-\rangle = \frac{|0\rangle-|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}},$$then

$$\psi_x = a|+\rangle+b|-\rangle$$,

projecting into the state $|1\rangle\langle1|:$

$$p_x = |\langle1|\psi_x\rangle|^2 = \left(|a\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+b\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|\right)^2 = \frac{1}{2}\left(|cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)-sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)cos\left(\phi\right)-isin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)sin\left(\phi\right)|\right)^2,$$

after expanding the module and finding the square:

$$p_x = \frac{1+r_x}{2}$$

For $p_y$ I get almost the same result:

Y-axis basis states:

$$|R\rangle = \frac{|0\rangle+i|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}, |L\rangle = \frac{|0\rangle-i|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}},$$

repeating the same routine as for $p_x$:

$$\psi_y = a|R\rangle+b|L\rangle$$,

$$p_y = |\langle1|\psi_y\rangle|^2 = \left(|ai\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+b(-i)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|\right)^2 = \frac{1}{2}\left(|cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)i-sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)cos\left(\phi\right)i+sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)sin\left(\phi\right)|\right)^2,$$

$$p_y = \frac{1-r_x}{2}$$

The result is strange, because I expected to get $\frac{1-r_y}{2}$

I think I made the mistake somewhere in basis definition, but I can't understand, where could it be.

Comment: To follow @ChadK, the *Bloch vector* for this state is $(r_x, r_y, r_z)$, where $r_x$, $r_y$, and $r_z$ are how you defined them. It is unclear what you mean by "the $p_z$ component of the Bloch vector." 

As you defined it, $p_z$ is the probability of measuring the qubit to be in the $|1\rangle$ state when measuring along the $z$-axis. What do you mean for $p_x$ and $p_y$ to be?

Comment: sorry for incorrect explanation, now I made some edits to my post)

Comment: When computing $p_y$, you ended up with the two terms receiving an $i$ phase factor (up to sign). But only the second term should receive this phase, i.e., your expression for $p_y$ should be $|a/\sqrt{2}-i b/\sqrt{2}|^2$.

Comment: @Semiclassical, could you please clarify it? expanding $\langle1|aR\rangle$ and $\langle1|bL\rangle$ both give imaginary multiplier, i.e. $ai$ and $-bi$, isn't it?

Comment: @ChadK, do you know, how to find $p_y$ correctly?

Comment: All of the formulas you give are correct (i.e. you haven't made any math mistakes). The bases you give are also correct (they are fairly standard results). It might be the case that the equations you wrote are not what you want to find. Could you clarify what $p_x$ etc. are? You call them expectation values, but they are probabilities.

Comment: Another strange thing about your question is that $\phi$, $\phi_x$ and $\phi_y$ are all expressions for arbitrary spin $\frac12$ vector, only in different rotated coordinate systems. Realistically, one of them is necessary (likely $\phi$). If I were to hazard a guess, what you want to find is the probability that an arbitrary spin vector measures up when measured in the $x$,$y$, or $z$ direction.  In that case, the probabilities are $p_x=|\langle +|\phi\rangle|^2$, $p_y=|\langle R|\phi\rangle|^2$, $p_z=|\langle 1|\phi\rangle|^2$

Comment: @Andrew, thank you for your comments!) the idea of my question is to find $p_x$, $p_y$ after applying $\frac{\pi}{2}x$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}y$ pulses and project each to the $|1\rangle$ state of the $Z-$basis

Answer (score 1):

Here's the explanation:

You have $|R\rangle=\frac{|0\rangle+i|1\rangle}{\sqrt 2}$, $|L\rangle=\frac{|0\rangle-i|1\rangle}{\sqrt 2}$ and you just created a state $\psi_y=a|R\rangle+b|L\rangle$, then you project it into $|1\rangle\langle 1|$ . But what does the $z$ basis look like from the $y$ basis? Let's see!

We can tell that $|0\rangle=\frac{|R\rangle+|L\rangle}{\sqrt 2}$ and $|1\rangle=\frac{|R\rangle-|L\rangle}{i\sqrt 2}$. This doesn't look like the form of the $y$ basis... instead, it looks exactly like the $x$ basis with respect to the $z$ basis, except for the global phase $i$ which doesn't do anything in the probability!

Your angles are defined with respect to your $y$ basis, and from the point of view of the $y$ basis, the $z$ basis looks like the $x$ basis relatively. So it's expected that you get $r_x$ again.

If you do the same thing to the $x$ basis, you'll notice that your $z$ basis looks like $x$ basis from $x$ basis as well.
So where does the $r_y$ go, though? Well, if we add a global phase $i$ on the $|L\rangle$, i.e, $|L\rangle=\frac{-i|0\rangle-|1\rangle}{\sqrt 2}$, then the $z$ basis would look like $y$ basis from $y$, and we'll get the $r_y$ term. The same thing can be done for $x$ basis. But I'm not sure if there's any point in doing either of that...

Comment: thank you so much for such a detailed answer! but I still didn't get some of your points: why $|0\rangle=\frac{|R\rangle+|L\rangle}{\sqrt 2}$ looks exactly like the $x$ basis? it is similar to $ |+\rangle = \frac{|0\rangle+|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$, but it is not the same...what is the rule for adding or removing the global phase? for me it is strange, that in some cases we can include the global phase and in others exclude it

Comment: another issue, that I didn't get: why do my angles defined with respect to $y$ basis? for me it is not evident, that I should get $r_x$ again...

Comment: Well, let's simplify the problem so it's easier to see where it goes wrong. Let's assume $\theta=\pi/2$, $\phi=0$, the state is originally in x+ direction, $a=b=1/\sqrt 2$. If we rotate it $\pi/2$ around Y axis, it should now face z- direction, which should result in probability 1 if measured in z- direction. But if we rotate it around the X axis, it should remain the same, because it's parallel to the axis! But from your equation, you get $|\psi_y\rangle=1/\sqrt 2 |R\rangle+1/\sqrt 2|L\rangle = 1/2 |0\rangle+1/2|0\rangle = |0\rangle$. So I suppose your rotation operation is wrong.

Comment: of course it's all clear, but this is exactly the issue)) I can't find, where my rotation operator goes wrong, because all my calculations for $p_x$ correct, but not for $p_y$, can you derive the correct expression for $p_y$ as I did for $p_x$?